# How to create another Wordpress account after re-installing Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am having problems creating a new wordpress account. I previously had an account on wordpress, I uninstalled wordpress as it was having problems trying to recover my wordpress account because it cannot identify my details. Now, when I re-install wordpress and enter new login details, it keeps saying I already installed wordpress. I am certain I have removed all the wordpress contents in my C: drive before re-installing wordpress.

Plus, I even uninstalled WAMP and still gives me the same result.

Here's a screenshot of what happens after I have enter new login details:
[image]

Note: I installed wordpress locally on my computer, I haven't used any hosting website.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone? There are 14 views here...

Answer (score 1):

Well it appears that there are still tables in your MySQL database.
I do not have enough details about your installation, but you should try to access your database (preferably with Phpmyadmin) and then clear everything from your previous install.

Try localhost/phpmyadmin

The other option is to look for the database file, and just delete that. But again, it depends on your installation where that file might occur and thus more information is needed.

Comment: I have tried this. I even uninstalled WAMP entirely to give me a fresh Phpmyadmin. :(